# Downgrade Ubuntu 18.04.3 kernel to original kernel

Tags: 18.04, kernel, downgrade, hardware-enablement-stack

On my machine, I run Ubuntu 18.04.3 with kernel version 5.4.0-050400rc5-generic. Unfortunately, VirtualBox and the NVidia drivers seem to have an issue with this kernel version because several compile processes (e.g., `/sbin/vboxconfig`) fail during installation.

I found out that, apparently, Ubuntu 18.04.3 actually was shipped with a 5.0 kernel.

Furthermore, I have read about the hardware enablement stack (HWE). This helps me to easily update the kernel version of my system with usual updates. Therefore, I suspect that manual installation of older kernels might not be advantageous.

My questions:

1. Which kernel version is an up-to-date Ubuntu 18.04.3 expected to have at this point, where only the recommended updates have been made?
2. What is the recommended way to go back to that kernel version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 was shipped with the 4.15 kernel.

Ubuntu 18.04 starting with .2 point release are shipped with HWE kernels.

HWE kernel versions are "rolling". Now it is 5.3. Kernel 5.0 is not supported any more on Ubuntu. If you did a normal upgrade on 18.04.3, you woild have the 5.3.

You can easily install the original 4.15 kernel by installing `linux-generic` meta package.

You an also install the current HWE kernel by installing `linux-generic-hwe-18.04`.

Beware that grub will always boot with the highest kernel version unless you select another one.

So if you want to use the current Ubuntu kernel, run

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

if you removed it previously. Then remove your mainline kernel.

Comment: That's true. I mean rolling, because you can install e.g with 5.0, then it is updated to 5.3, etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Turned out, 5.3 was already installed, just selecting that kernel in the Grub boot menu was sufficient. And VirtualBox and the NVidia drivers worked fine with 5.3, so the kernel was indeed the issue.